# Version control an application that is cloned from a boilerplate

Tags: git, github, workflow

What is your workflow if you have a "boilerplate" pushed in github, and you'll be creating another project out of it.

### Would you clone it and change remote?:

1. git clone `link-of-github-repo`
2. git remote set-url origin `link-of-ANOTHER-repo`
3. do app-specific changes, like changing readme, package.json etc.
4. commit and push?

If there are *better* ways, can you cite some.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an exact duplicate of the repository on GitHub without marking it as a fork. GitHub documents how to [duplicate a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) in their help.

> To make an exact duplicate, you need to perform both a bare-clone and a mirror-push.
>
> Open up the command line, and type these commands:

```bash
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
# Make a bare clone of the repository

cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
# Mirror-push to the new repository

cd ..
rm -rf old-repository.git
# Remove our temporary local repository
```

Comment: could not be assumed as an exact duplicate though, since I am cloning a "project-seed" or "boilerplate"